# Which sensor should be used to determine whether device has been tilted UP or Down by using Android Sensor

Tags: android, android-sensors

Which sensor should be used to determine whether device has been tilted UP or Down by using Android Sensor?

By using the following code:

```
SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(mRotationMatrix, null, mValuesAccel,mValuesMagnet);
SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(mRotationMatrix,
SensorManager.AXIS_Y, SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X, R2);
SensorManager.getOrientation(R2, mValuesOrientation);
```

I'm getting three orientation values(azimuth,pitch,roll)
How can I use three orientation values to determine whether device has been tilted up or down.

Answer (score 8):

To get the device tilt, as well as other attack angles you will need to register a listener for TYPE_ACCELEROMETER and TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD events:

```
mngr = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

accelerometer = mngr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
magneticField = mngr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

int rate = SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME; // or other
mngr.registerListener(sensorListener, accelerometer, rate);
mngr.registerListener(sensorListener, magneticField, rate);
```

Once listener is activated, you will need to call

```
  SensorManager.getOrientation()
```

to obtain current values for azimuth(z), pitch(x) & roll(y).

[image: Orientation angles]

You can find a detailed code example here: http://www.codingforandroid.com/2011/01/using-orientation-sensors-simple.html

Answer (score 1):

i think Accelerometer Sensor is used to determine whether device has been tilted UP or Down...